# JFugue 5 external midi device

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi, jfugue

Been trying for a long time to send a sequence to a midi device with jFugue 5:

```
     MusicReceiver device = getDeviceByName("name");

     Player player = new Player(); 
     Pattern pattern = new Pattern("A");    

     device.sendSequence(player.getSequence(pattern));
```

Can't go beyong *"Unhandled exception type MidiUnavailableException"* on *"device.sendSequence"*.

```
     static MidiDevice.Info getDeviceInfoByName(String name) {
        for (MidiDevice.Info info : MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()) {
          if (info.getName().equals(name)) {
            return info;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      static MusicReceiver getDeviceByName(String name) {
          return new MusicReceiver((MidiDevice) getDeviceInfoByName(name));
      }
```

Comment: Can you give your entire stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.media.sound.MidiInDeviceProvider$MidiInDeviceInfo cannot be cast to javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast an instance of `MidiDevice.Info` that you get from your `getDeviceByInfo` to a `MidiDevice`. Replace your `getDeviceByName` function with the following:

```
static MusicReceiver getDeviceByName(String name)
        throws MidiUnavailableException {
    MidiDevice.Info info = getDeviceInfoByName(name);
    return new MusicReceiver(MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info));
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Unhandled exception type MidiUnavailableException

Comment: From the javadoc: "MidiUnavailableException - if the requested device is not available due to resource restrictions" -- so I'm guessing that there is something wrong with your particular MIDI device

Comment: But both "MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info))" and "device.sendSequence(player.getSequence(pattern))" are underlined, I can't even compile, so how could this be a problem of a particular device

Comment: Sorry I forgot that MidiUnavailableException isn't a RuntimeException. This latest edit will fix that issue but you will need to throw a try/catch around `MusicReceiver device = getDeviceByName("name");` or do some other kind of error handling

Comment: javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: MIDI IN receiver not available
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice.createReceiver(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice.getReceiver(Unknown Source)

Comment: yes and the Exception for the try/catch is what I've posted above

Comment: OK, this sounds like a problem with your computer/MIDI system/Name of your MIDI device.

Comment: I can easily connect to it through different software but not through java code :S

Comment: Well, that's beyond the scope of your original question. Perhaps try another device?